# Cannot store the document_id

Tags: php, mysql

I have `tb_sentence` table :

```
=========================================================================
| id_row | document_id | sentence_id |          sentence_content        |
=========================================================================
|   1    |     1       |    0        |  Introduction to Data Mining.    |
|   2    |     1       |    1        |  Describe how data mining.       |
|   3    |     2       |    0        |  The boss is right.              |
=========================================================================
```

I wanna tokenize the sentence_content, so the `tb_tokens` tables will contain :

```
==========================================================================
| tokens_id | tokens_word  | tokens_freq | sentence_id  | document_id    |
==========================================================================
|     1     | Introduction |        1    |       0      |       1        |
|     2     | to           |        1    |       0      |       1        |
|     3     | Data         |        1    |       0      |       1        |
|     4     | Mining       |        1    |       0      |       1        |
|     5     | Describe     |        1    |       1      |       1        |
etc...
```

here's my code :

```
$sentence_clean = array();
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT document_id FROM tb_sentence ORDER BY document_id ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1)) {
    $doc_id[] = $row1['document_id'];
}
$q2 = mysql_query('SELECT sentence_content, sentence_id, document_id FROM tb_sentence ') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {
    $sentence_clean[$row2['document_id']][] = $row2['sentence_content'];
}
foreach ($sentence_clean as $kal) {
    if (trim($kal) === '')
        continue;
    tokenizing($kal);
}
```

with the function of tokenizing is :

```
function tokenizing($sentence) {
    foreach ($sentence as $sentence_id => $sentences) {
        $symbol = array(".", ",", "\\", "-", "\"", "(", ")", "<", ">", "?", ";", ":", "+", "%", "\r", "\t", "\0", "\x0B");
        $spasi = array("\n", "/", "\r");
        $replace = str_replace($spasi, " ", $sentences);
        $cleanSymbol = str_replace($symbol, "", $replace);
        $quote = str_replace("'", "\'", $cleanSymbol);
        $element = explode(" ", trim($quote));
        $elementNCount = array_count_values($element);

        foreach ($elementNCount as $word => $freq) {
            if (ereg("([a-z,A-Z])", $word)) {
                $query = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO tb_tokens VALUES ('','$word','$freq','$sentence_id', '$doc_id')");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is The `document_id` cannot be read and cannot be inserted in tb+tokens table. How to call those `document_id` ? thank you :)

EDITED QUESTION :
every words (the result of tokenizing) has `document_id` and `sentence_id`. my problem is cannot call the `document_id`. how to call both `sentence_id` and `document_id` in every words ?

Comment: Good job presenting the question.  EXCEPT ... "the problem is The document_id cannot be read and cannot be inserted in tb+tokens table" -- can you be more precise?  What goes wrong?

Comment: @Smandoli sorry if my english is bad. Every `sentence_content` has the `document_id`. I need to insert the tokens words with the document_id too, but I can't read the document_id

Comment: There is no `$row['document_id']` because you did not include `document_id` in the select list of the second query.

Comment: @Michael oh, yes, I've added `document_id` but it still does not work

Comment: You should not be appending to an array here, since you are specifying the key, dong use `[]`:  `$sentence_clean[$row2['document_id']][] =` should be `$sentence_clean[$row2['document_id']] =`

Comment: @Michael for my case, there're many documents that every documents has many sentences. so I need to determine `Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => Introduction to Data Mining [1] => Describe how data mining.  [2] => Array ( [0] => The boss is right)`

Comment: @igos Sorry - I didn't notice you had many per document id. in that case, you had it correct with `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need these code:

```
$q1 = mysql_query("SELECT document_id FROM tb_sentence ORDER BY document_id ") or die(mysql_error());
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($q1)) {
    $doc_id[] = $row1['document_id'];
}
```

array of $doc_id is never been used

```
if (trim($kal) === '')
        continue;
```

$kal is an array and don't need to be trimmed

```
$sentence_clean[$row2['document_id']][] = $row2['sentence_content'];
```

because you're going to record the sentence_id, it should be $row2['sentence_id'] not []

(of course you should make sure, there won't be same sentence_id in same document_id or else you should concat it)

this is a few corrections from me:

```
$sentence_clean = array();
$q2 = mysql_query('SELECT sentence_content, sentence_id, document_id FROM tb_sentence ') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($q2)) {
    $sentence_clean[$row2['document_id']][$row2['sentence_id']] = $row2['sentence_content'];
}

foreach ($sentence_clean as $doc_id => $kal) {
    tokenizing($kal, $doc_id);
}

function tokenizing($sentence, $doc_id) {
    foreach ($sentence as $sentence_id => $sentences) {
        $symbol = array(".", ",", "\\", "-", "\"", "(", ")", "<", ">", "?", ";", ":", "+", "%", "\r", "\t", "\0", "\x0B");
        $spasi = array("\n", "/", "\r");
        $replace = str_replace($spasi, " ", $sentences);
        $cleanSymbol = str_replace($symbol, "", $replace);
        $quote = str_replace("'", "\'", $cleanSymbol);
        $element = explode(" ", trim($quote));
        $elementNCount = array_count_values($element);

        foreach ($elementNCount as $word => $freq) {
            if (ereg("([a-z,A-Z])", $word)) {
                $query = mysql_query(" INSERT INTO tb_tokens VALUES ('','$word','$freq','$sentence_id', '$doc_id')");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I parse the document_id to the function

Comment: oh, silly me.. yes, you're right.. ! great ! thank you very much @ivantedja. I learn many things from you :)